# Local push notifications with database verification

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I had an idea when I saw that my university classmates who used my online schedule site were not always up to date when the schedule changed.

The idea is that I want to send a push up notification locally with a service worker who will check if the schedule has been modified and that at regular intervals.

I have two concerns.

1_ how to set up a regular check of the database (eg: every 15 min).

2_ is it possible to use Ajax with the service worker while the the browser are close.

And all this without a vaped key and without using the server except to check the database.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The question is not clear enough. A web program can not run without browser. So it must be open in a tab or window to work.

Comment: so for receive push up notification the browser must be open ?

Comment: The website must be open in the browser, or you create a PWA which can be added as an icon to the device. PWAs also use the browser but act like a native app.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do a fetch request without any user interaction after you have received a push notification. What you can do instead is to display a push notification informing the user to click on it to reload the data from the DB after the user landed on a page.

Comment: yes i can do that, but it will be disturbing for the students.